# Bug in jQuery window.resize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a website so whenever you click on the button with `id="slider-toggle"` the menu opens up. It works fine when you load the page for the first time.

The problem occurs whenever you resize the window. Whenever you resize the window and then click on the button, console log says "open it, close it". whereas it should only say either "open it" or "close it".

Then whenever you continue to resize the window and then click on the button it goes something like "open it, close it, open it, close it, open it, close it and so on".

As far as I'm concerned there's something wrong with jQuery's resize() method.

Or can any one see any flaw within my code?

```
var container = $('#container');
var menu = $('#desktop-menu');

function myswipemenu(){

  //toggle function
  function toggleSwipeMenu(){
    if(container.hasClass("open")){
      console.log("close it");
    }
    else {
      console.log("open it");
    }
  }

  $('#slider-toggle').click(toggleSwipeMenu);

}
function callback () {
  windowsize = $(window).width();

    menu.removeClass('slidermenu');
    container.removeClass('thecontent');
    menu.insertAfter($(".header-main"));


  if (windowsize < 1160) {

    menu.addClass('slidermenu');
    container.addClass('thecontent');

    myswipemenu();
  }
  else {

    menu.removeClass('slidermenu');
    container.removeClass('thecontent');
  }
}

$(window).ready(callback);
$(window).on('resize', callback);
```

Comment: where do you add/remove the "open" class from the container?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the below function in the resize event.

```
myswipemenu()
```

And the events are getting bind again and again.

Remove the call to that function in the resize event it wont get called again and again. 
If you are resizing by window dragging then that function will is being called multiple times and will overload the browser.

Comment: If its the right answer then please mark it as answered as the question will be removed from the Unanswered Queue.

Comment: Ahh ok, so how do I do I call that function whenever the window resizes? Is there an alternative to Jquery resize()?

Comment: Keep the declaration of the the function toggleSwipeMenu() out of the myswipemenu(); or rather just use the toggleSwipeMenu(). You have declared a function within another function. Keep the function declarations different and functions call different. Not a good practice to do which you have tried.